# Is it possible to add text or html tag in HTML using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure, it is possible to add **Text** or **HTML** Tag. I am using JQuery **insertBefore()**, **insertAfter()**, **nextAll()**, but I can't do it.

**Note:** The **text** doesn't have an HTLM Tag.

See code below:

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<img alt="Title 10" src="images/1.jpg" />
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
**Here I want to Add**

<h2>Title 2</h2>
<img alt="Title 10" src="images/1.jpg" />
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
**Here I want to Add**

<h2>Title 3</h2>
<img alt="Title 10" src="images/1.jpg" />
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
**Here I want to Add**
```

Thanks!

Comment: where you want to insert html in your example

Comment: I want to add the HTML tag below the text (Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbbhcfk1/). The text nodes are printed to the console.

After selecting the elements you can use

```
.wrap('<span class="text"></span>');
```

to wrap it in a html tag, or normal jquery if you wish to do something else with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like this.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("<span>Hello world!</span>").insertAfter("p");
});
```

Syntex is

```
$(content).insertAfter(selector)
```

You can also use.

```
$('#bla').after('<div id="space"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("element").html(text_or_html_to_add) //or 
$("element").append(text_or_html_to_add) //or 
$("element").prepend(text_or_html_to_add) //or 
$("element").text(text_or_html_to_add)
```

functions available in jQuery.

Please check here for examples..

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/